# AMD E2-6110 with Radeon R2 Vulkan support

Tags: drivers, radeon, vulkan

As per the title I have an AMD E2-6110 APU with Radeon R2 Graphics, its a laptop. I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 I have the vulkan-utils, mesa-vulkan-drivers, libvulkan1

but when I run vulkan-smoketest I get:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
what():  VkResult -3 returned
zsh: abort      vulkan-smoketest
```

so does this device support vulkan?